# Integration in d-dimensional spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

Can someone please tell me why
$$\left(\int_0^\infty dr\, e^{-r^2}\right)^d=\int_0^\infty dr\,r^{d-1}S_d e^{-r^2}?$$

Why doesn't $d$ end up joining the exponential?

Comment: Do you mean $\int dr^d e^{-r^2}$?

Comment: No. LHS comes from the Gaussian integral giving $\pi^{d/2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your potential $(\int ...\text dr)^d$ by a multi dimensional integral
$$\left(\int_0^\infty\text dr\, e^{-r^2}\right)^d = \int_{R^d}\text d^dr e^{-\left(r_1^2+...+r_d^2\right)} = \int_0^\infty\text dr\,r^{d-1}S_d e^{-r^2}$$

Comment: wrong sign I think.

Comment: Thanks and just to make sure, do you mean $d(r^d)$ or $d^dr$?

Comment: @LorentzNoether I meant $d^d$ Sorry, I was in hurry.